# Json response reactnative fetch login data

Tags: react-native, fetch

Im trying to fetch my login data using the login fetch method below which raises an error.
I'm not sure why it raises this error and where its going wrong.

i get this error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res._bodyText')]
```

**login fetch method**

```
createUser: (username, password) => {
    return (
      fetch('http://192.168.0.140:80/auth/login/', {
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        credentials: 'omit',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password
        })
      })


    )
  },
```

**in my login.js**

```
state = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  }

login = () => {
    if (this.state.username === '') {
      alert('Enter username !')
    } else if (this.state.password === '') {
      alert('Enter Password !')
    } else {
      api
        .createUser(this.state.username, this.state.password)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        //If response is in json then in success
        .then((responseJson) => {
          //Success
          console.log(responseJson)
        })
        //If response is not in json then in error
        .catch((error) => {
          //Error
          console.error(error)
          alert(error)
        })
    }
  }
```

**calling the login()**

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this.login()}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Text bold style={styles.buttonText}>
                        Login
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

Comment: Could you show what res._bodyText is?

Comment: i dnt have it defined but it is meant to check the if the username and password are a sucess...im new to reactnative so i'm not very sure about it

Comment: Just do this `console.log(res._bodyText)` and give it to us

Comment: i updated my login to use a different jsonresponse which now works but does not raise an alert for the user

Comment: cuz you forgot to put the alert inside the `then` closure

Comment: how can i add it correctly?  like if successful display ```Login successful``` if not ```check credentials``` something like that

Comment: Look nice with that messages

Comment: kindly help me to add it to my code bcz i dnt know how to do that

Comment: I left you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could help you:

```
import {Alert} from 'react-native'

login = () => {
    if (this.state.username === '') {
      Alert.alert('Enter username !')
    } else if (this.state.password === '') {
      Alert.alert('Enter Password !')
    } else {
      api
        .createUser(this.state.username, this.state.password)
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.ok) {
              Alert.alert('Login successful')
            }else{
              Alert.alert('Check credentials')
            }
        })
        //If response is in json then in success
        
        //If response is not in json then in error
        .catch((error) => {
          //Error
          Alert.alert('Check credentials')
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: this displays ```'Login successful'``` regardless of wether the details are correct or not. it doesnt display ```'Check credentials'``` alert

Comment: To 'Check credentials' alert get display you api must return an error

Comment: yes im adding incorrect data to test it but it doesnt show up

Comment: You request are returning http error code 400 ?

Comment: yes the api raises a 400 error ```Bad Request: /auth/login/
[12/May/2022 01:35:32] "POST /auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 400 68```

Comment: I update my answer check it out again,

Comment: a small question....if in case later in the project i want to replace ```Login Successful``` with navigating successful users to home screen how can i do that? so in place of the alert i redirect the user instead

Comment: using `this.props.navigation.navigate('nameOfScreenYouWantToNavigate')`

Comment: i have another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214113/how-to-add-navigation-navigate-reactnative) i would appreciate your help kindly have a look at it